# SublimeText Emmet comments after adding / to br and hr tags

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I am using the following code in my Emmet.sublime-setting to add auto comments after classes and ids. This works fine but it is now also adding forward slash on my `<br>` and `<hr>` tags when I type *br[TAB]* or *hr[TAB]* becoming `<br />` and `<hr />`.

How can I change it to go back to the regular non trailing slash while keeping the comments.

```
{
    "preferences": {
        "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /<%= attr('id', '#') %><%= attr('class', '.') %> -->"
    },

    "syntaxProfiles": {
        "html" : {
            "filters" : "html, c",
            "html" : "html"
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing slash is controlled but the output profile: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/

Another possible reason is that your document contains XHTML doctype, in this case Emmet tries to automatically match documents’ format

Comment: Doctype is html but isn't set on most pages as I am using Smarty and its includes and extends. Looking at my settings above I thought I was using regular html and not xhtml